# Java 8 Streams : get non repeated counts

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Here is the SQL version for the input and output :

```
     with tab1 as (

        select 1 as id from dual union all
        select 1 as id from dual union all
        select 2 as id from dual union all
        select 2 as id from dual union all
        select 5 as id from dual 
        )

    select id from tab1 group by id having count(id)=1;

Output is Id=5 and count is 1
```

As 5 is non repeated.How do i implement it using JAVA 8 streams?

I tried below but obviously it is giving wrong  result

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                myList.add(1);
                myList.add(1);
                myList.add(2);
                myList.add(2);
                myList.add(5);

                Long f =  myList.stream()
                          .distinct().count();

                System.out.println(f);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
long result = myList.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                   Function.identity(),
                  Collectors.counting()))
         .entrySet()
         .stream()
         .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == 1)
         .map(Entry::getKey)
         .count();
```

Well you collect all the elements to a `Map<Integer, Long>`, where the key is the value itself, and value is how many times it is repeated. Later we stream the entry set from that resulting map and `filter` only those entries that that have a count of `1` (meaning they are not repeated), later we `map` to `Entry::getKey` - to get that value from the List and count.

Comment: I was trying to find something more elegant but not sure it's possible.

Comment: @assylias there is, but only if the number of elements that are repeated is even...

Comment: Thanks Your code returns the value but i just need the Count .In my case the count is 1 .And please can you please explain your code a bit as i am new to Java and Streams

Comment: @assylias IFF that number is even you could do `Set<Integer> set = List.of(1, 1, 2, 2, 3)
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        Function.identity(),
                        Function.identity(),
                        (left, right) -> null

                ))
                .keySet();` for example...

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to filter repeated elements out of the list but it's not very efficient so I would only use it if the list is small:

```
List<Integer> result = myList.stream()
                             .filter(i -> Collections.frequency(myList, i) == 1)
                             .collect(toList());
```

Comment: why is it not efficient ?

Comment: @OracleMokey It's an O(n2) algorithm as each `frequency` calls iterates over the whole list.

Comment: @OracleMokey `import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;`

Comment: This is my actual code :
 
`Map<String, List<AlertKpi>> cnt = alertKpiList.stream()
    .filter(a -> calculatecount(a) || (  a.getBreachStartDate().isBefore(today) ||  a.getBreachStartDate().equals(today) )  )  
    .filter(i -> Collections.frequency(alertmgmtKpiList, i) ==1)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(k -> k.getStatus()));
`
I want to pass getBreachStartDate() in the frequency parameter but not able to pass

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, here's a Java 8 way which doesn't make use of streams:

```
Map<Integer, Long> frequencyMap = new LinkedHashMap<>(); // preserves order

myList.forEach(element -> frequencyMap.merge(element, 1L, Long::sum)); // group, counting

frequencyMap.values().removeIf(count -> count > 1); // remove repeated elements

Set<Integer> nonRepeated = frequencyMap.keySet(); // this is your result
```

This uses [`Map.merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) to fill the map with the count of each element. Then, [`Collection.removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) is used on the values of the map, in order to remove the entries whose value is greater than `1`.

I find this way much more compact and readable than using streams.

Answer (score 1):

You may do it like so,

```
Map<Integer, Long> countByNumber = myList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
List<Integer> uniqueNumbers = myList.stream()
    .filter(n -> countByNumber.get(n) == 1)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

First create a map using the value and the number of occurences. Then iterate over the `List` of numbers, get the occurences from the `map` for each number. If the number of occurences is 1, then collect it into a separate container.

If you want to do it in one go, here it is.

```
List<Integer> uniqueNumbers = myList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), 
        Collectors.counting()),
    m -> myList.stream().filter(n -> m.get(n) == 1).collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option for you to consider:

```
    //Create a map where the key is the element you want to count and the value is the actual count
    Map<Integer, Long> countByItem = myList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Function.identity(), //the function that will return the key
                Collectors.counting())); //the function that will actually count the occurences

    //Once you have that map, all you need to do is filter for the registers with count == 1
    List<Integer> result = countByItem.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == 1)
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: the *same* thing I wrote... :|

Comment: Not really, your code return the total of entries that have count == 1. The query in the question return all the entries that have count == 1, not the count. Also I splitted the solution in two statemets for better readability and added comments.