# Print unique values from collection using Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

I need to get only unique values from the collection( values which do not have any dublicates in collection).
For example, this code:

```
ArrayList<Integer> g =  new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,6));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(g.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).distinct().toArray()));
```

gives me this result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

However I want the result:

```
[3, 4]
```

Is there any way to do it with Stream API?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51879493/java-8-streams-get-non-repeated-counts) answer your question?

Comment: You could eliminate this problem entirely by using a Set...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
List<Integer> source = Arrays.asList(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6);
List<Integer> processed = source.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1)
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(processed);
```

Result:

```
[3, 4]
```